# Which letter of recommendation to use for graduate application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, recommendation-letter

I am currently studying in a CS Bachelor's program in the EU and applying for CS Master's programs next year. I have successfully asked 4 people for recommendation letters, but I don't know which one should I use for application. Here are their description:

- Letter from the professor of a course related to planned Master's studies. Very good grade.
- Letter from the professor of a course not related to planned Master's studies (still in the same discipline). Good grade.
- Letter from the professor of a course related to planned Master's studies, but it's a course during the current semester. It has been just half a semester though, so I'm not sure if they have enough information to write about me. Good grade (for now).
- Letter from my supervisor during last year internship (in the industry), very related to planned Master's studies.

Personally, I feel like the last one can say the most about me. The professors just barely know me as someone who took their class and got a good grade. However, I have heard that employer's letter are usually not preferred for Master's application. Most schools require 1-3 recommendation letters, so I think I should come up with an order of their "strength" to   use for the application.

Any suggestion for which one should I prioritize would be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked for similar questions here?

Comment: @BryanKrause I have looked but found mostly situations where people return to Master's studies after working for some time in the industry, so they have a hard time finding an academic referral. For the letter from a professor mid-semester, I could only find this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54270/asking-professor-for-letter-of-recommendation-before-finishing-class

Comment: Maybe try https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brecommendation-letter%5D+who

Answer (score 1):

None of these are great. The best letter writers are people you have worked with enough that they can honestly and confidently predict your success in graduate study. If you know any of the professors outside the classroom then they might be ok. The internship person might be ok if they have had graduate study and know what it is like.

If the masters you plan is course (not research) based then the professors might have a good idea, otherwise not.

Pick the ones you think might be the most positive if all else fails. You can judge that better than we can.